# How to build Flutter widget based on two Firestore collections

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections in Firestore:

events:
    title
   coachId

coaches:
   name

I made a widget 'EventsPage' with StreamBuilder which shows events. Now I need this widget to show coach name for every event - something like coaches[event['coachId']['name']. How can I get 'coaches' collection before 'EventsPage' widget is built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested `StreamBuilder`s

```
Widget nestedStreamBuilders() {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: firstStream,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.none:
          return Text('Select lot');
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return Text('Awaiting bids...');
        case ConnectionState.active:
        case ConnectionState.done:
          return StreamBuilder(
            stream: secondStream,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot secondSnapshot) {
              if (secondSnapshot.hasError)
                return Text('Error: ${secondSnapshot.error}');
              switch (secondSnapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('Select lot');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Text('Awaiting bids...');
                case ConnectionState.active:
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  return BuildYourWidgetHere();
                  // you can build your widget here because we have the both data 
              return null; // unreachable
            },
          );
      }
      return null; // unreachable
    },
  );
}
```

if you need `FutureBuilder` this is the example : [FutureBuilder_Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54967652/10685785)