# How to get a stream value and then call another stream based on the previous value using Flutter with firestore

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the Ids of users i'm following from a firestore stream and then call another stream with the posts of my followings with the ids from previously.

I don't know if this is the right way to architect it and if so how to implement it with flutter.. I've been trying streamBuilder for the first call, but I don't know how to make the second stream call with a list of ids.

The function that I used to get the followings Ids

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> followingUsersContent(String uid){
return _firestore.collection("following").document(uid).collection("userFollowing").snapshots();
  }
```

and to get their posts:

```
Stream<DocumentSnapshot> myContentList(String userId) {
    return _firestore.collection("posts").document(userId).collection("userPosts").document().snapshots();
  }
```

This is how I retrieve the first list of Id's from the widget:

```
postWidget(){
    return Container(
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
       stream: usersContentProvider.followingUsersContent(profileId),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text("There's no data");
            }

            if (snapshot.hasData) {

                 List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = snapshot.data.documents;

                 List<UserFollowing> userInfoList = usersContentProvider.getFollowingsUidToList(docs);

                 return testUserID(userInfoList); 
               }

              },
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
Widget testUserID(List<UserFollowing> userInfoList){
    return Container(
      child: Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: userInfoList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, i){

            return Text(userInfoList[i].uid ?? "There's no data", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),);
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

So far so good everything is fine.

Now should I put another stream builder inside the listView.Builder(){} "I don't think it's a good idea".. because it is retrieving a list of uid with the (itemBuilder context, i). Or is there a better way to call the stream with all the uids I have.
Ps the uids are stored in the UserFollowing model:

```
class UserFollowing{
  final String _uid;


   UserFollowing(this._uid);

   String get uid => _uid;
}
```

and stored from here:

```
List getFollowingsUidToList(List<DocumentSnapshot> docList){
    if (docList != null){
      List<UserFollowing> followingUidsList = [];
      docList.forEach((document){
        String uid = document.data["uid"];

        UserFollowing userPost = UserFollowing(uid);
        followingUidsList.add(userPost);
      });
      return followingUidsList;
    }
  }
```

All I'm left with now is to communicate a new stream with userFollowing.uid.

How can I do it? thanks.

Comment: I think you can use nested `StreamBuilders` you can see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55258901/10685785)

Comment: @ciplionat my stream function has an identifier which needs to be users id. This is the model from where i'm getting the ids.. they've been retrieved from the first stream `List<UserFollowing> userInfoList = usersContentBloc.getFollowingsUidToList(docs);`  now do i need to do `userInfoList[0].uid` or is there another way to do it.